# Azure Web App Free SSL Stage

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm in the process of moving our site to Azure Web App (S1).  I might be over thinking this but need to create a temp domain for my team to QA the temp Azure site before I move the prod site to Azure.

I've done the following so far:
 1. Create Azure Web App account and deployed site mysite.azurewebsites.net - done
 2. Create subdomain stage.mycompany.com - done
 3. Create cname #2 and point to #1 - done

Since stage.mycompany.com is temporary (until we move the actual site over), I don't want to purchase an SSL for this.

I thought I could just create an SSL using openssl and install that cert on Azure.  I tried that but get "Not secure" in chrome for the cname.

Will this idea work (free SSL for cname azure web app) but I just didn't install the ssl correctly?

Comment: It would help if you listed the steps you did when creating and also configuring the cert in Azure because it definitively works.

Comment: There's free TLS with a proper cert on `https://{your-webapp-name}.azurewebsites.net`, why bother?

Answer (score 1):

> I thought I could just create an SSL using openssl and install that
>   cert on Azure. I tried that but get "Not secure" in chrome for the
>   cname.

Probably, you have not imported the certificate in your **Trusted Root Certification Authorities** directory on your machine. You can check configurations on your side as following steps.

If you create a certificate using OpenSSL, you should export the certificate with the private key then upload the certificate .pfx file to the Azure portal. [Export certificate to PFX.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl#export-certificate-to-pfx)

Or, you can generate a self-sign certificate with PowerShell.

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -DnsName "stage.mycompany.com" -FriendlyName "MySiteCert" -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(1)
```

**Export the certificate.** Then run MMC, Follow the path to locate the newly generated certificate in your machine. File--- Add\Remove Snap-In---Certificates----add---computer account. Copy the certificate from Personal directory to **Trusted Root Certification Authorities** directory. Also, you need to export the certificate (.pfx file) with private Key.

On the Azure side, you need to upload and bind the newly generate the self-sign certificate to your websites.

- Map your subdomain `stage.mycompany.com` to your websites. You can select Custom domains in your web app page. Add hostname `stage.mycompany.com`, refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#create-the-cname-record).
- [Bind your SSL certificate.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl#bind-your-ssl-certificate) Click SSL settings in the left navigation of your web app. Upload your newly .pfx certificate, and bind your SSL certificate with SNI-based SSL type.

After that, you can access the website with https://stage.mycompany.com. I test it in my lab with IE and Chrome explore as below:

[image]